Flask-Migrate got partially broken
I am trying to do yet another migration for the database of my app.
Unfortunately, by development environment got freaky, and it seems to be partially broken.
In particular, I get the error "Command db not recognized", but the commands seems to execute just fine.
If I search for an explaination, I can see that this is due to the package flask-migrate not installed. However, it is installed.
(venv) sapphirewanderer87@devz:~/project_app/appname$ python3 -m flask db --history
Command db not recognized
Usage: python -m flask db [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'python -m flask db --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --history
(venv) sapphirewanderer87@devz:~/project_app/appname$ python3 -m flask db history
Command db not recognized
7756b9787967 -> 78595f915015 (head), Add columns to data table
daae6e730c39 -> 7756a9787967, Add new field
5e070714dfeb -> dbbed4730c39, add first table
<base> -> 5e070714dfeb, initial create

Do you have any ideas?
